# How to wait for onAuthStateChanged to be executed first?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have created a separate file for all pages to check that user is logged in or not and get the uid from it,so I created a a file call **GetLoginedUser.js**

Code :

```
import { app, db } from "./FiiireBaseConfig";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

export async function getUser() {
  var uId ="Uid Will be here";
 

  console.log("Get User Started");

  await onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (user) => {
    if (user) {
     
      uId = user.uid;
    } else {
    
      alert("No User Found");
    }
  });

  console.log("get user ended");
  return uId;
}
```

Now I imported this function into another file
Code :-

```
 const { getUser } = require("./GetLoginedUser");
    
    var user ;
    async function updateUserImage() {
      user = await getUser();
      console.log("user:" + user);
    }
    updateUserImage();
```

But the problem is it don't wait for **onAuthStateChanged** and returns the initial value. So the output will come like **User: Uid will be here** not updated!

Comment: I  tried to add **await**  at "onAuthStateChanged" but vs code suggests that await will not be applied, so remove unnecessary await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use `await` when calling `getUser`, you need to return a promise from it. Something like this:

```
export async function getUser() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (user) => {
      if (user) {     
        resolve(user.uid);
      } else {
        reject("No User Found");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `new` before the `Promise` constructor, and the arrow `=>` between its arguments and the opening brace

Comment: Woops... good catches Ali! Thanks for those.  I've clearly been doing too much Flutter/Dart recently. ;-)